# Count of unread messages as a badge on the app icon not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-push

I've implemented push notification via App Center Push for my xamarin.forms project. On my android 9 device "Honor P 10 lite" the counter for the unread messages is not visible any more. 
I know that with android 9 so called "notification dots" (little circle on the app icon,to inform the user that there are new messages) were introduced.
If this is enabled (via Settings -> Notifications -> App Icon Badges -> Badge Display Mode : New Notifications) the dots is visible when new messages arrived. And by long press on the app icon I can see the notification and also the correct notification count is shown on the right.
If i switch to "Badge display mode: "Unread messages" and afterwards send a push notification to my app, the badge counter doesn't get visible (altough the notification is appearing on the screen)

I've tried to set the badge count in code (`notificationChannel.SetNumer()`); and also tried to set the target android version to the highest API level.

Expected result: Show a badge with the correct number of unread messages on the app icon.
Actual result: No badge is shown when new push notifications were send to the device.

Do you also face this problem or do you have any idea how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be a bug with Android 9 i will have to take a look at this one, is this happening in any other Android 9 devices?

Comment: Huawei 8X I've facing the same issue

Comment: Well this seems to be a bug you might want to report this on Google : https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my problem. I've reported the issue
https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-DotNet/issues/868

Comment: This seems to be more of an android bug! not app center's